# Row stripping when there are hidden elements

Tags: css

I have a list that needs to have row stripping so they can tell what goes with what. It's kind of odd because the list has two items sitting next to each other on each line.

I had the row stripping working with something like this

```
.itmRow:nth-child(4n + 2), .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

And this was great, but now there are some rows that are hidden. And even though the rows have a `display:none;` on them the stripping is still 'seeing' them.

I've been trying with something like this

```
.itmRow:nth-child(4n + 2), .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.itmRow.hideRow, .hideRow ~ .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 2), .hideRow ~ .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
.hideRow ~ .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 3), .itmRow:nth-child(4n + 4) {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
```

where I am taking in the hidden row and sort or reapplying the background color. But it's not quite right and I can't seem to tweek it just so. Any help?

A js fiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/zazvorniki/a8p3vjbu/1/

Comment: you will have to relay on javascript to go through the DOM and count elements not hidden to update background-color. nth-child() goes though the dom (no matter if elements are hidden or not, it's there and increments the count) . Thats a job CSS cannot do unless you already now which is hidden or not ....

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, I, unfortunately, cannot do this is js.  I can't completely remove them from the dom because I have other things depending on them. That's why I was trying to do the above. It almost works too

Comment: the *removed* answer is deleted since you need them. I now say that you have to count them, check position it stands (4n/4n-1), update that position if previous is hidden and finally add a class or style for the bg-color needed. CSS itself is unable to do it unless you write selectors for each possible case and specifity  ... could be thousands ... if you understand how nth-child works, then you know it is not what to relay on ;) here. an easy option is draw the stripes from the parent with a repeating- gradient if each rows have the same height

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, I still can't use javascript for this. I really can only use css, why I did not tag javascript. I am tied beyond hiding them and it would be too long to fully explain. There are only four possible cases, white background shown, white background hidden, grey background shown and grey background hidden.

Comment: so here the gradient idea ;) https://jsfiddle.net/wq9sej40/ CSS is definitely not a programing language :( There can be hacky ways, gradient is the easiest one of them but can break really easily

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, that kind of works, but it needs to be every other item, So the first one white, the next one grey and so on